# On the STM32F4, why does setting the main clock source as the PLL corrupt the rest of the program?

Tags: c, assembly, arm, corruption, stm32f4

first question here, thank you for your patience.

I'm facing an issue with an STM32F446VET6-based board (the ST-B96B-F446VE from STMicroelectronics), using the StdPeriph library v1.8.0. I've narrowed down the issue to a `str` instruction in the SetSysClock function:

```
;722          RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_SW_PLL;
; RCC->CFGR = 0x9400
; RCC_CFGR_SW_PLL = 0x02
ldr r2, [pc, #36]   ; (0x80005a8 <SetSysClock+284>)
ldr r3, [pc, #36]   ; (0x80005a8 <SetSysClock+284>)
ldr r3, [r3, #8]
orr.w   r3, r3, #2
str r3, [r2, #8]    ; r2 = 0x40023800, r3 = 0x9402
```

The instruction result should be that the second bit of RCC->CFGR (SW1) be set to 1, in order to set up the PLL as the main clock source.

Instead, the bit stays at 0, and a whole lot of code past 0x08000000 (in the flash) is overwritten. For instance, this line in SystemInit():

```
; SCB->VTOR = FLASH_BASE | VECT_TAB_OFFSET; /* Vector Table Relocation in Internal FLASH */
ldr     r3, [pc, #12]   ; (0x8000484 <SystemInit+96>)
mov.w   r2, #134217728  ; 0x8000000
str     r2, [r3, #8]
```

ends up rewritten as:

```
; SCB->VTOR = FLASH_BASE | VECT_TAB_OFFSET; /* Vector Table Relocation in Internal FLASH */
bic.w   r3, r3, #262144 ; 0x40000
str     r3, [r2, #0]
ldr     r3, [pc, #24]   ; (0x8000494 <SetSysClock+8>)
```

Letting the program run in this state and pausing it again shows some more overwriting happened, again at the same lines:

```
; SCB->VTOR = FLASH_BASE | VECT_TAB_OFFSET; /* Vector Table Relocation in Internal FLASH */
b.n     0x8000476 <SystemInit+86>
subs    r0, #0
ands    r2, r0
```

and it hangs in the subs and ands instructions.

Incidentally, replacing the line `RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_SW_PLL;` by `RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_SW_HSE;` resolves the issue. No corruption happens, and main() executes properly. But now it's using another clock source, with no idea what implications this carries.

---

Is there some way to revert to the default state of using the PLL as the main clock source, and avoid the flash corruption?

Comment: If you break at the first instruction after a reset (often an assembly label called `Reset_Handler`), and inspect the flash, is it still corrupted on the next run after this happens? If no (which I *strongly* suspect), this points at some runtime error which simply makes the flash look broken, i.e. flash reads are failing. What frequency is the PLL at when you switch to it? Is is stable and all that? Also, consider switching to Cube.

Comment: Also, note that many debuggers fail to adapt when you change the clock source on the fly.

Comment: Just did this. Indeed the flash does not look corrupted anymore. What can cause this? Can it be the flash not keeping up with the PLL's frequency? I've tried upping the Flash Wait State to 11 cycles instead of 6, to no avail. How can I test for PLL stability? I'll look into Cube.

Comment: The main issue is not a debugger issue at this point: running the program without debugger, the processor doesn't go into main() if the PLL is selected as the main clock source. Using HSE, main() runs correctly and the LEDs blink as I've programmed them. I'll keep your remark in mind nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

> I've narrowed down the issue to a str instruction in the SetSysClock function:

That usually means you forgot to set the flash wait states before. Flash memory ist rather slow - it tops usually at around 20 MHz without wait states for many MCUs. Trying to run it too fast result in reading garbage.

Reference Manual and datasheet should state how many wait states your target frequency requires for flash access. Note: It is safe (but slower) to run the flash at maximum wait states.

Comment: This particular part apparently specifies max clock 30MHz for zero wait states and supply 3.3V. (The manual chapter 6.3.1 table 17)

Comment: The clock source and flash latency are set in system_stm32f4xx.c, which I haven't written. Two lines above the faulting line, the source reads: `FLASH->ACR = FLASH_ACR_PRFTEN | FLASH_ACR_ICEN |FLASH_ACR_DCEN |FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_5WS;` I tried using `FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_15WS`, to no avail.